# Line spacing before and after bullet list (Word 365; Windows 10)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365, bullets, line-spacing

When I write a bulleted list in Word 365, I would like to dispense with the line space between the text line preceding the list and the first bullet point, and the line space coming between the last bulleted point and the text line. So that the bullet list doesn't form a separate paragraph in fact.

In the screenshot below, for example, I would prefer not to have the two line spaces which confuse rather than clarify.

[image: text example showing unwanted line spaces]

Comment: although you can't format text here as you wish, you can always add screenshots. Please do so, as currently it's not easy to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on home and locate the paragraph section, as shown here:
[image: microsoft word ribbon]

In the paragraph section, click the circled icon and then click remove space before paragraph. You can click remove space after paragraph as well. That should do what I think you're looking to do. A bulleted list is always going to make its own paragraph, but that should fix the spacing between it and the others.

[image: paragraph section]